# Ordered Collection of key-value Pairs in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a 2D table with columns: *Language* and *Proficiency*, which I need to populate with the input.

I've created a method:

```
public void typeLanguages(@NotNull List<String> languages,
                          @NotNull List<SkillLevel> skillLevels) {

    if(languages.size() != skillLevels.size()) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }

    IntStream.range(0, skillLevels.size()).forEach(i -> {
        typeAndConfirm(languagesFld.get(i), languages.get(i));
        typeAndConfirm(skillFld.get(i), skillLevels.get(i).getLangSkill());
    });
}
```

`IntStream` is used, so `i`-th *language-skillLevel* pair is inserted in `i`-th row.

`SkillLevel` is an enum which implements `getLangSkill()` method which returns, one of four proficiency levels as String

However, there is a risk that the user can provide Lists of different sizes (*although guarded*) or that they could mix up the order and give themselves the wrong proficiency scores.

AFAIK there are no tuples in Java. I tried using Map, but I can't see any method that could let me use `i`-th element of map.

Comment: Please clarify the problem a little more. Give an example of what you want to achieve and/or the shortest way to reproduce it.

Comment: In a `Map` implementation, the order of the elements is determined by the implementation, and the concept of an `i`th element may not make sense. For instance, `HashMap` has no guarantees of ordering (essentially "random"), `TreeMap` orders based on a binary tree structure (and is thus sorted), and `LinkedHashMap` orders elements based on insertion order. Rather than keeping multiple maps or lists, you might really want a class/object (like `LanguageScore`) which can keep its own `Map<Language, SkillLevel>` internally for a specific result.

Comment: Also, any particular reason to use Intstream.range?

Comment: @justanotherguy the soultion I provided solves the problem using Lists, I want user to be able to provide language-skills pairs, so they don't mix them

Comment: @Rogue It doesn't matter which language is inserted first to table, as long as language and corresponding skill end up in the same row

Comment: @hetacz with keeping a `Map<Key, Value>`, when you `map.put(Key, Value)`, then the `Value` associated with `Key` will never arbitrarily change. It will only change if you either mutate the `Value` you inserted, `Map#put` again, or use one of the mutator methods in `Map` (e.g. `#compute`). A `Map` is (almost) never internally represented by a pair of lists, instead it usually uses the `Key` to denote a specific location where the `Value` is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't misuse Collections

The two pieces of data: *language* and *level* don't a have any value separately, only when you have them both they are useful. That means they have to constitute an *object*. An attempt to utilize a `Map` just for the purpose of describing the relationship between the two properties would be an abuse of collection, which would result in unmaintainable code.

So instead of maintaining the two separate lists, which makes your code brittle, you can define a [***record***](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) (*or a **class** if you want it to be mutable or using a version earlier than Java 16*) that will combine both properties into a single object:

```
public record LanguageLevel(String language, SkillLevel level) {}
```

With that instead of `List<String>` and `List<SkillLevel>` you will deal with a `List<LanguageLevel>`.

In case if you would want to sort the objects in a list and there's only one particular way of sorting that makes sense in your application - so called *natural order*, then you can make `LanguageLevel` implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

But if in your domain model, these pairs have no *natural order*, and they might be sorted differently depending on a situation that have a look at the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

You can define multiple comparators to facilitate different ways of sorting. For example:

```
Comparator<LanguageLevel> bySkillDescAndByLang = 
    Comparator.comparing(LanguageLevel::level).reversed() // assumption that SkillLevel implements Comparable<SkillLevel>
        .thenComparing(LanguageLevel::language);

List<LanguageLevel> languages = // initialize the list
languages.sort(bySkillDescAndByLang);
```

Comment: Good answer. Also need to support ordering per the Question. Perhaps implement `Comparable` on the record.

Comment: @BasilBourque *implement Comparable* - it depends on how OP wants to order them. In my opinion `LanguageLevel` has no natural order, i.e. we can order them by level (let's say in descending order) and by language in alphabetical order, or we may want to make the first comparison by language. That's a job for a `Comparator`.

Comment: So I should implement Comparable<SkillLevel> like this in my record:
    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull SkillLevel o) {
        return this.skillLevel.ordinal() - o.ordinal();
    }
And I can happily use it?

Comment: @hetacz `SkillLevel` has a *natural order* (like ` NoProficiency -> ElementaryProficiency -> ... -> NativeProficiency), therefore it makes sense for it to be comparable And it seems like your implementation of `SkillLevel` is an `enum` - that's fine, it's a very good choice, and it means that it is **already comparable** (it's implicit parent class `java.lang.Enum` implements `Comparable<E>`). No need to do any changes to the `SkillLevel`.

Comment: @AlexanderInvanchenko, thank you very much for extra input about Comparable, it wasn't really part of the question at all, but I'm really happy that I learned something new thanks to you, However when I try implementing your solution, I get an errorjava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is it because I use records instead of classes?

Comment: @hetacz May be you are trying to sort a structurally immutable `List`, like a list created using `List.of()`, `Arrays.asList()`, or generated from a stream using `toList()` operation? You can create an instant share of your code with https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ and drop and link to it.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Yes, I am trying to sort list, I don't know how to call it on method, here is my code jdoodle.com/ia/scK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245607/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-hetacz).

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Use a `NavigableMap` such as `TreeMap`
- Define a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) (a nominal tuple) with two member fields that implements `Comparable`

For the map approach:

```
NavigableMap < String , SkillLevel > map = new TreeMap<>() ;
map.put( someLangString , someSkillLevel ) ;
map.put( someOtherLangString , someOtherSkillLevel ) ;
…
```

The key-value pairs will be automatically sorted by the natural order of the string keys.